# Usar clausula In en Where con Case When

Tags: sql, sql-server, while, subconsultas

Tengo un problema usando Sql Server. Necesito condicionar el código de mis planes dependiendo si busco un plan individual o un plan padre_individual.

Si es un Plan individual solo mostrará el plan del código asociado, en cambio si es padre, mostrará todos los planes asociados al código de jerarquia.

```
    Declare @CPlan int --Valor viene desde el módulo c#
    Declare @EsPadre Bit
    Declare @Planes Table(Plan int Not Null)

    Set @EsPadre=(Select EsPlanPadre From PlanesPadres Where CodPadre=@CPlan)
    If @EsPadre=1
       Begin 
          Insert Into @Planes
          Select CodPlanHijo
            From PLanesHijo
           Where CodPlanPadre = @CPlan
       End
    Select Plan From Planes
    Where CPlan In (Case When @EsPadre=1 Then (Select Plan From @Planes)
                                         Else @CPlan
                    End)
```

No puedo utilizar Exec @strQuery pues tengo 10 opciones con las de 200 lineas cada una que debo estructurar siendo que el detalle esta ahí.

¿Existe alguna forma de ejecutar correctamente la consulta?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. Te puede interesar leer [ask], para que la misma sea bien recibida, pues el escenario no esta nada claro. La pregunta y se se puede, y la respuesta es si. Pero para recibir una respuesta apropiada, basada en el código, tendrás que establecer las tablas, los datos y la salida deseada, entonces, quizá tú pregunta obtenga el resultado deseado.

Comment: ¿qué es `@strQuery`? Ah, ya que si es urgente, lee esto: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152/21

Answer (score 0):

Después de ver una infinidad de algoritmos y de pruebas de aplicación relacionadas, generé la solución:

```
Where (@EsPadre=0 and CPlan=@CPlan) Or (@EsPadre=1 and Cplan In (Select PlanHijo From PlanesPadres Where CodPadre=@CPlan)
```

Espero y sirva para próximos colegas.

Muchas gracias.